# Error "field declared as a function" when trying to use methods in c++ struct in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, struct

When creating defining struct in a c++ header file and making the appropriate bridging header, it returns the error "field declared as function". It seems that Xcode still treats it as a basic C header file even though I changed the header extension to .hh or .hpp. I was led by ChatGPT to believe that when using a C++ struct in swift making an objective-c interface is not necessary.

Code for a simple command line Xcode project:

Person.hpp

```
#ifndef Person_hpp
#define Person_hpp

#include <stdio.h>

struct Person {
    int age;
    void growUp();// Error field 'growUp' declared as function
};

#endif /* Person_hpp */
```

Person.cpp

```
#include "Person.hpp"

void Person::growUp() {
    age += 1;
}
```

Test-Bridging-Header.h

```
#include "Person.hpp"
```

main.swift

```
import Foundation

let alex = Person(age: 5)

print(alex.age)
```

Comment: A header file's extension is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is whether the code that includes it is C or C++. Xcode is not a compiler, so it has no direct relevance on how something gets compiled; at most it might have indirect relevance via the command that it executes to run the compiler. Unfortunately, that information is completely absent from the question, so it's unlikely that anyone will be able to provide any more information.

Comment: The code that includes it is the bridging header

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you can tell Xcode, on a file by file basis, what language to assume.

Comment: `field growUp declared as function` is a C compiler error. ChatGPT knows nothing,  thinks nothing. It  compiles (in other meaning of word) mixed sources from internet.

Comment: OP, Swift cannot bridge to C++, only C.  So write a header file that you can compile as C

Comment: You could have a `struct CPerson` with just the `age` field, and then let the C++ `Person` inherit from that and add the member function.